# Array and String cannot have their containment checked error when trying to search array using jq

Tags: json, shell, sh, jq

I have a json file that looks roughly like this:

```
{
    "default": [
        {
            "name" : "Joe Bloggs",
            "email" : "joe.bloggs@business.org"
        }
    ],
    "groups": [
        {
            "recipients" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Jane Bloggs",
                    "email" : "jane.bloggs@business.org"
                }
            ],
            "orgs" : [  
                "Service A",
                "Service B",
                "Service C"
            ]
        },
        {
            "recipients" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Bill Gates",
                    "email" : "bill.gates@business.org"
                }
            ],
            "orgs" : [
                "Service D",
                "Service E"
            ]
        },
        {   
            "recipients" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Steve Jobs",
                    "email" : "steve.jobs@me.com"
                }
            ],
            "orgs" : [
                "Service F",
                "Service G"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Using jq I want to be able to search using one of the orgs, so for example 'Service A' and return only the recipients information

I can search recipients easy enough using jq like:

```
cat /path/to/file.json | jq -r '.groups[] | .recipients[] | select(.name | contains("Jobs"))' )
```

to return

```
{
  "name": "Steve Jobs",
  "email": "steve.jobs@me.com"
}
```

But If I try to search via the orgs array, I get an error:

```
cat /path/to/file.json | jq -r '.groups[] | select(.orgs | contains("Service A"))' )
```

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:46): array (["Service A...) and string ("Service A") cannot have their containment checked
```

Is it possible to do what I am looking for with jq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead off `contains` you'll need `index` <sup>[[docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example51)]</sup> to check if there's an index with the value `Service A`:

```
.groups[] | select(.orgs | index("Service A"))
```

Will output:

```json
{
  "recipients": [
    {
      "name": "Jane Bloggs",
      "email": "jane.bloggs@business.org"
    }
  ],
  "orgs": [
    "Service A",
    "Service B",
    "Service C"
  ]
}
```

###### [JqPlay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NJjdIgKfEB)

---

We can extend that to output only the `recipients` like so:

```
.groups[] | select(.orgs | index("Service A")) | .recipients | first
```

Where we use `first` to select the first object from the `.recipients` array. The output will be:

```json
{
  "name": "Jane Bloggs",
  "email": "jane.bloggs@business.org"
}
```

###### [JqPlay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pb9XoUCHxr)

Comment: This is what I was looking for - thanks very much. I had gotten as far as select in the jq guides I read and thought that was enough for it to do what I needed - but can see that the index function was what I was looking for.